# Problema com case no script

Tags: linux, script, shell-script, shell

Alguém me explica por qual motivo meu script está retornando apenas a opção "Error"?

```
#!/bin/bash

#==========================#
DATA=$(date +%T) #Vai mostrar a hora com os mins
CORTE=$(date +%k) #Vai mostrar apenas a hora, tipo 18 ou 12 horas, sem os mins
#==========================#

echo $CORTE #Verificar como ficou o resultado da variável CORTE

case $CORTE in #Dependendo da numeração da variável CORTE irá mostrar diferentes mensagens
    [6-11]) 
        echo "Bom dia!"
        ;;
    [12-17])
        echo "Boa tarde!"
        ;;
    [18-23])
        echo "Boa noite!"
        ;;
    [0-5])
        echo "Boa noite!"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Error"
        ;;
esac

echo "Horário: $DATA" #Para finalizar irá mostrar as horas com os mins
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que me lembro o case não reconhece ranges, tente assim:

```
if ((6<=$CORTE && $CORTE<=11)); then
    echo "Bom dia!"
elif ((12<=$CORTE && $CORTE<=17)); then
    echo "Boa tarde!"
elif ((18<=$CORTE && $CORTE<=23)); then
    echo "Boa noite!"
elif ((0<=$CORTE && $CORTE<=5)); then
    echo "Boa madruga! :-)"
else 
    echo "Error"    
fi
```

Se vc for obrigado a utilizar o `case` acho que vai ter que fazer com `or`, um trabalhão, algo como:

```
case $CORTE in
    6|7|8|9|10|11) echo 'Bom dia!';;
    12|13|14|15|16|17) echo 'Boa tarde!'
    # ....
esac
```

Comment: Utilizei o pipe que nem você me recomendou e funcionou, obrigado.